# Beamer - rendering table borders while uncovering rows

Tags: tables, beamer

I have a table with borders that I am trying to reveal row by row. However, the borders are rendering badly:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\frame{
\frametitle{Title}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline Row1L & Row1R \\ \hline\pause
Row2L & Row2R \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

renders as

[image: bad borders]
[image: slide 2 is OK]

while changing the first row to

```
\hline Row1L & Row1R \pause \\ \hline
```

gives me

[image: bad borders version 2]

for the first slide instead. Other positions for `\pause` throw errors. `\uncover` and `\onslide` were giving similar problems. Is there any way to get rid of the dangling line from the first example or make something sensible out of the second?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One possibility is to use

```
\\ \hline\noalign{\pause}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\frame{
\frametitle{Title}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline Row1L & Row1R \\ \hline\noalign{\pause}
Row2L & Row2R \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thought I understood what the TeX primitive \noalign does but this application has me confused as to how it is working here?

Comment: @R.Schumacher code in `\noalign` is executed between the rows, in particular after tex has added the right border of row 1 and before it starts row 2 by adding the left border, which is exactly what you need. (+1 to Harish;-)

Comment: Fantastic, exactly what I needed. Thanks so much!