# Tabular: lines with \pause get line added

Tags: tables, beamer, arrays

When I try to build this:

```
\usepackage{array}
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Bibliotheken}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Bibliothek} & \textbf{Sprache} & \textbf{max. Rang} & \textbf{SIMD} & \textbf{Multithreading} & \textbf{Besonderheiten}\\\hline
        \textit{Fastor} & C++ & n & \checkmark & $\times$ & Overheadreduktion durch fehlende BLAS-Calls \\\hline\pause
        \textit{Blitz}++ & C++ & 11 & $\times$ & $\times$ &    \\\hline\pause
        \textit{Eigen} & C++ & 250 & \checkmark & \checkmark &  \\\hline\pause
        \textit{XTensor} & C++ & n & \checkmark & \checkmark & effiziente BLAS-Calls \\\hline\pause
        \textit{Taco} & C++ & n & $\times$ & $\times$ & Runtime Code-Generieung und Compilierung \\\hline\pause
        \textit{NumPy} & Python & n & \checkmark & \checkmark & effiziente BLAS-Calls \\\hline\pause
        \textit{Tensorflow} & Python & 250 & \checkmark & \checkmark & Operator-Baum-generierung und Optimierung \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{frame}
\end{beamer}
```

I get this fail:

[image: fail]

How can I fix this? The best solution would be one where I have to change as little as possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229995/121799) you can use `\noalign` here. This answer is also to convert your snippet into a compilable example, but I will be happy to remove it if others feel it is a duplicate.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Bibliotheken}
    \adjustbox{width=\textwidth}{\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Bibliothek} & \textbf{Sprache} & \textbf{max. Rang} & \textbf{SIMD} & \textbf{Multithreading} & \textbf{Besonderheiten}\\\hline
        \textit{Fastor} & C++ & n & \checkmark & $\times$ & Overheadreduktion durch fehlende BLAS-Calls \\\hline\noalign{\pause}
        \textit{Blitz}++ & C++ & 11 & $\times$ & $\times$ &    \\\hline\noalign{\pause}
        \textit{Eigen} & C++ & 250 & \checkmark & \checkmark &  \\\hline\noalign{\pause}
        \textit{XTensor} & C++ & n & \checkmark & \checkmark & effiziente BLAS-Calls \\\hline\noalign{\pause}
        \textit{Taco} & C++ & n & $\times$ & $\times$ & Runtime Code-Generieung und Compilierung \\\hline\noalign{\pause}
        \textit{NumPy} & Python & n & \checkmark & \checkmark & effiziente BLAS-Calls \\\hline\noalign{\pause}
        \textit{Tensorflow} & Python & 250 & \checkmark & \checkmark & Operator-Baum-generierung und Optimierung \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]