# \pause inside tabular

Tags: tables, beamer, pause

I'm using Beamer for my slides and I need to show my tabular gradually, so after each click I get one row at a time.

I'm using `\pause` that works with some errors:

```
\begin{frame}
      \frametitle{}
        \scalebox{0.80}{
                \begin{tabular}{|*{2}{c|}}
                    \hline
                    Column one & Column Two\\
                    \hline
                    ValueRow1Colum1 & ValueRow1Colum2\\
                    \hline\pause
                    ValueRow2Colum1 & ValueRow2Colum2\\
                    \hline
                \end{tabular}
}
\end{frame}
```

I'm getting this result after the first click:

[image]

What is wrong is this vertical line in the begining of the row2.

How can I delete this one, because it should be shown only after the last click.

Comment: Possible duplicate? [Beamer - rendering table borders while uncovering rows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229992/134144)

Comment: This solution worked fine but the footer-page  doesn't appear on the slide. It appears only when all the rows are printed, is there a solution?

Comment: Could you please make a compilable MWE that allows others to reproduce the issue you describe?